# How to make a rest call in kie workbench

Tags: rest, drools, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-workbench

I am a newbie to kie workbench, I am using drools 6.3.0 and want to write a code in kie workbench for making a rest call. 
With extensions tab, I made a angular page and now I want to make a rest call.
But i am not getting how to use Rest Api in kie workbench.
Can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way : User default REST task.
Programmatic way : You need to create Java Handler. Use Apache HttpClient to implement programmatic REST call in "executeWorkItem" of your "WorkItemHandler", upload the jar in KIE Workbench. Then configure your "Task" to use this handler.

Comment: Can you please explain what is a default REST task. Could you please also provide a sample program/ Example for using Rest in kie workbench